# Why is select-element not working for some Android browsers/versions on default Magento 1.7 iphone theme?

Tags: iphone, magento, mobile, select, themes

I encounter a strange issue for configurable products on [Magento 1.7 default iphone theme](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/coalesce-functioning-on-impatience-t-shirt.html). If I visit this site with a mobile device (Android 2.3.3/default browser), I just cannot choose the product option from select-element. It works quite nice on same device and mobile versions of Firefox and Opera though.

On my colleagues mobile device (Android 4, default browser) it is just working great. What could be the cause of this behavior and how can it be fixed?

Comment: We ran into a similar issue, it was my colleague that fixed it, so I'm not sure on the details, but I believe it was actually a css issue. Another element on the page was in front of the select (though you couldn't see anything), which was preventing you clicking the select box.

Comment: I believe he used https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre to help diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

select menus to come back when I removed data-position="fixed" from both the header and footer (before and after). I then went back to the original example, made only that one change, and found that it also fixed the problem there.